# zoo create new column with dynamic column name

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to add a column to a zoo object.  I found merge which works well

```
test = zoo(data.frame('x' = c(1,2,3)))
test = merge(test, 'x1' = 0)
```

However when I try to name the column dynamically, it no longer works

```
test = merge(test, paste0('x',1) = 0)
Error: unexpected '=' in "merge(test,paste0('x',1) ="
```

I have been working with data frames and the same syntax works

```
test = data.frame('x' = c(1,2,3))
test[paste0('x',1)] = 0
```

Can someone help explain what the problem is and how to get around this?

Comment: Is it really "the same syntax [that] works?" Have you tried `paste0('x',1) = 0`?

Comment: I stand corrected.  What I really meant to say is I am hoping to find a solution that allows me to add as well as name a new column dynamically in zoo just like I can do with a data frame

Comment: Not so beautfful but you could convert your zoo object to a data frame, operate on it and convert it back:  `read.zoo(replace(fortify.zoo(test), paste0("x", 1), 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `setNames` :

```
setNames( merge(test, 0), c(names(test), paste0("x", 1)) )
```

or `names<-.zoo` like this:

```
test2 <- merge(test, 0)
names(test2) <- c(names(test), paste0("x", 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution very easy and elegant. It uses the `eval()` function to interpret a string as an R command. Thus, you are completely free to assemble the string exactly the way you want:

```
test = merge(test, paste0("x",1) = 0)
# does not work (see question)

test[,"x1"] <- 0
# does not work for uninitialized columns

test$x1 <- 0
# works to initialize a new column

# so lets trick R by assembling this command out of strings:
newcolumn <- "x1"
eval(parse(text=paste0("test$",newcolumn," <- 0")))
# welcome test$x1 :-)
```

Comment: An alternative of this solution is to call the `$<-.zoo` method directly. It might be easier to read, but not by much: ``test <- zoo:::`$<-.zoo`(test, newcolumn, 0)``.

Answer (score 0):

Merge expects a string as variable name, it doesn't understand variable names that are return values of functions. Why not

```
test = zoo(data.frame('x' = c(1,2,3)))
var <- paste0('x',1)
test = merge(test, var = 0)
```